# Grails 3.2 - Select with pagination and one-to-many association

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

Grails 3.2 comes with some major updates to GORM. How would one do a query like:

```
def c = Cat.createCriteria()
List<Cat> data = c.listDistinct(){
    createAlias('furType', 'ft)
    createAlias('kittens', 'kitten')
    createAlias('kitten.furType', 'kft')
    or {
        ilike('ft.color', 'orange')
        ilike('kft.color', 'orange')
    }
    maxResults 10
    firstResult 10
}
```

Currently this query only shows 5 results instead of 10 when each cat has two kittens.

Edit: Edited example to show how duplicate Cats can get called.

Comment: does both kittens each cat has also have furType orange? If not then    ilike('kft.color', 'orange') would limit the number of returned results.

Comment: They do not. I'm just trying to paginate cats that have a kitten with furType orange. But in this particular situation, you would never have two kittens with the same furType color.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your criteria query. May be I didn't understand your question correctly. If you could clarify, then that would be great.

Comment: If I create 10 cats, each with two kittens and run that query, I get cats with ids 6-10 listed. I believe this is because the distinct projection is making it so 10 cats are queried but then projected down to 5 in the final list. I need to be listing 10 cats.

Comment: Set firstResult to 0

Comment: Setting firstResult to 0 shows cats with ids 1-5. If I keep firstResult at 10 but remove the maxResults line, I get all cat ids from 6 on up. The difficulty seems to be getting firstResult and maxResults, which are necessary for pagination, to play nice with listDistinct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def c = Cat.createCriteria()
List<Cat> data = c.listDistinct(max: 10, offset: 10){
    createAlias('kittens', 'kitten')
    createAlias('kitten.furType', 'kft')
    ilike('kft.color', 'orange')
}
```

A better way, if you are paginating by creating links, you can create links in the following format

```
http://example.com/controller/action?offset=10
```

and then in your controller action, you can do the following

```
params.max = 10
def c = Cat.createCriteria()
List<Cat> data = c.listDistinct(params){
    createAlias('kittens', 'kitten')
    createAlias('kitten.furType', 'kft')
    ilike('kft.color', 'orange')
}
```

Comment: This causes an exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to groovy.lang.Closure